# Write a program to add two lists, Input is A=[1,2,3] ,B=[9,4,1] , output = [1,0,6,4].. i.e 123+941 = 1064?

Tags: python-3.x

The below code works fine when I give input like 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 in the codeforces editor, but how can I take input like [1,2,3] and [4,5,6]?

```
list1 = list(map(int,input().split(',')))
list2 = list(map(int,input().split(',')))

slist1 = [str(i) for i in list1]
slist2 = [str(i) for i in list2]

slist1_join = "".join(slist1)
slist2_join = "".join(slist2)

total =  int(slist1_join) + int(slist2_join)
final = list(str(total))
final1 = [int(i) for i in final]
print(final1)
```

Comment: So you want that the user type the list with brackets `[1,2,3]` instead of just the values `1,2,3`?

Comment: yeah, could you please help me with that

Comment: We are not a factory to make homework. Please read the tutorial. We help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = list(map(int,input()[1:][:-1].split(',')))

list2 = list(map(int,input()[1:][:-1].split(',')))
```

The `[1:]` will remove the first character (the "`[`"), and the `[:-1]` will remove the last character (the "`]`"). Note that this will also accept input such as "`a6,8,5%`" and work with it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the `eval()` function.

```bash
list1 =  eval(input())
list2 =  eval(input())
slist1 = [str(i) for i in list1]
slist2 = [str(i) for i in list2]
slist1_join = "".join(slist1)
slist2_join = "".join(slist2)
total = int(slist1_join) + int(slist2_join)
final = list(str(total))
final1 = [int(i) for i in final]
print(final1)
```

##### Output

```bash
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[5, 7, 9]
```

Using eval() allows the user to enter [1,2,3] or 1,2,3 as an input.